# How to install Gitlab on Apache and a subdomain or different path

Tags: git, apache, ubuntu, server, gitlab

I'd like to know if there was a possibility of installing gitlab on Ubuntu running Apache automatically without having it installed on the "root" of my webserver.

For example, if I installed gitlab with the provided installer from the gitlab site, it would be reachable directly under www.example.com.

What I want is to have it installed at like git.example.com or www.example.com/git, is this possible?

Sorry if my question sounds completely retarded and noobish, but I'm struggling with this problem since a few days and I don't seem to be able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes? try this way.